# Publishing a 2D array to Excel worksheet

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

The function works as an "asset class allocation" engine (with constraints in the Param range) and simulates a portfolio model on each row of the array. I attempt to publish the array onto the worksheet with four methods, each of them fails.

Those Params are configured in M3:O6 as {Min 5, Max 100, Step 5} for each asset weight in assets A,B,C,D.

The function fails to paste the 2D array into Excel. There are 970 permutations, so array is 970x5. Is this a size issue? Code works fine up to `PrintArray AllocArray, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").[A1]`

`Sub PrintArray(Data As Variant, Cl As Range)
    Cl.Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)) = Data
End Sub`

```
Function ConfigureArrayFolly()

Dim Param() As Variant
Param = Range("M3:O6")

Dim AMin, AMax, AStep, BMin, BMax, BStep, CMin, CMax, CStep, DMin, DMax, DStep As Double

AMin = Param(1, 1): AMax = Param(1, 2): AStep = Param(1, 3)
BMin = Param(2, 1): BMax = Param(2, 2): BStep = Param(2, 3)
CMin = Param(3, 1): CMax = Param(3, 2): CStep = Param(3, 3)
DMin = Param(4, 1): DMax = Param(4, 2): DStep = Param(4, 3)


Dim nSim As Double: nSim = (1 + (AMax - AMin) / AStep) * (1 + (BMax - BMin) / BStep) * (1 + (CMax - CMin) / CStep) * (1 + (DMax - DMin) / DStep)
Dim nAsset As Double: nAsset = 4 ' Count {A, B, ... , F}

'Debug.Print nSim

Dim AllocArray() As Variant
ReDim AllocArray(1 To 970, 0 To nAsset)

Dim Sim As Integer: Sim = 1
Dim A As Double
Dim B As Integer
Dim C As Integer
Dim D As Integer

For A = AMin To AMax Step AStep
    For B = BMin To BMax Step BStep
    'If (A + B) > 100 Then GoTo endB
        For C = CMin To CMax Step CStep
        'If (A + B + C) > 100 Then GoTo endC
            For D = DMin To DMax Step DStep
                        ' nAsset is the count of set {a1, a2 ... an}
                        ' AllocArray(1, 2, 3) = (Sim, a1, a2)

                        'Constraints
                        If (A + B + C + D) <> 100 Then GoTo endD
                        Debug.Print Sim; A; B; C; D

                        AllocArray(Sim, 0) = Sim
                        AllocArray(Sim, 1) = A
                        AllocArray(Sim, 2) = B
                        AllocArray(Sim, 3) = C
                        AllocArray(Sim, 4) = D
                        Sim = Sim + 1

                       ' Debug.Print "Sim "; Sim; AllocArray(1, 1)
endD:
            Next D
endC:
        Next C
endB:
    Next B
Next A


' Print to sheet - Method One  (fails)
    Dim NumRows As Long: Dim NumCols As Long
    NumRows = UBound(AllocArray, 1) - LBound(AllocArray, 1) + 1
    NumCols = UBound(AllocArray, 2) - LBound(AllocArray, 2) + 1
    Set Destination = Range("D20").Resize(NumRows, NumCols).Value = AllocArray

' Print to sheet - Method Two (fails)
    'Sheets("Test").Range("D20").Value = AllocArray(1, 1)

'Print to sheet - Method Three (fails)
    PrintArray AllocArray, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").[D20]

'Print to sheet - Method Four (fails)
    Range("D20:H989").Value = AllocArray

    Sheets("Test").Range("D20").Resize(Sim, NumCols).Value = AllocArray

    'Range(D20:G6002) = AllocArray

    ConfigureArrayFolly = nSim
    End Function
```

Comment: What exactly fails? If I delete methods one - three, method 4 works. The array gets printed, the last row remains empty.

Comment: Tks. There is nothing pasted into Excel even for method 4 - my system VBA 7.0 Excel 2010 v 14.

Comment: `ReDim AllocArray(1 To 970, 1 To 5)`  and why is `nAsset` a `Double`? It should be an `Integer`.

Comment: Most of your variables are variants, so it might be useful to type them more tightly.   If you `Dim A, B As Double` then only B is a double: A is Variant.

Comment: Your code work fine for me: no errors and the output range populates with numbers

Comment: It occasionally works, moreoften in the IDE with Watches on the second attempt. Will investigate why inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

Your array has different lower bounds for each dimension.

You need to adjust for that by adding 1 to `UBound(Data,2)` :

```
Sub PrintArray(Data As Variant, Cl As Range)
    Cl.Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2) + 1) = Data
End Sub
```

Comment: Tks. Even when i adjust the AllocArray to start at 1 and go til 5 (instead 0 to 4), the array doesn't print to sheet....

Comment: Any error message, or just nothing happens?  Your question doesn't provide much information about what happens when you run your code.  If you populate the destination range with some dummy content then does your code overwrite that?  Maybe your array doesn't have any content.

Comment: Debug A,B,C,D and AllocArray watch show that the array is populated. The cell gives #VALUE error and nothing is written/overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

A few pointers.

- You are correct in using `Range("D20").Resize(NumRows, NumCols).Value = AllocArray` syntax.
- `AllocArray` needs to be sized with `ReDim AllocArray(1 to NumRows, 1 to NumCols)`
- It is correctly defined as `Dim AllocArray() as Variant`
- The contents need to be either a `Double` or a `String`. You are mixing integers and doubles and I think Excel has a hard time with this (I may be wrong). Set `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` as `Double`
- `Dim nAsset As Integer: nAsset = 5 ' Count {A, B, ... , F}` this is an integer, why was it defined as a `Double`?
- Use 32-bit integers for counting. `Dim Sim As Long: Sim = 1`. The max. value for an `Integer` is 32767 so you may be overflowing. This may apply to other `Integer` types in your code too.
- You already know how big the array is, you don't need the `UBound()` and `LBound()` calls.

Comment: Tks, nSim is 160,000 so when defined as Integer may be overflowing.

Comment: Tks, these pointers are great.  I don't know the size (rows) of AllocArray (becuase of the (A+B+C+D)<>100 constraint) until after populating it. I do know the max size (it's nSim).  I use the `UBound()` and `LBound()` to trap new size.